# Extending div to bottom of page not working

Tags: css, html

I have been trying to fix the length of this div for awhile, and I'm sure it is something completely simple, just not seeing it.  The div for the content "page" is extending well beyond the footer and I can manipulate the length with the min-height property in css however I want to make sure that the footer/"page" div extend to bottom regardless of the content so I don't want to set a definite length for the div.

**EDIT**:
 jsfiddle:     http://jsfiddle.net/F2SMX/

**Footer cs**

```
#footer {
    background: #365F91;
    color: #000000;
    width:100%;
    height: 35px;

    position:relative;

    bottom:0px;
    clear:both;
}

#footer p {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 77%;
}

#footer a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#footer a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

changing footer position from relative to absolute had no change

Comment: Image: http://i.imgur.com/rnD53Na.png

Comment: please provide a fiddle!!

Comment: You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ in the future. It's a lot better to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go old school.....add this to you css of `#footer`

```
bottom: -500px;
padding-bottom: -500px;
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7pfMF/1/)

**CSS**

```
#footer {
        background: #365F91;
        color: #000000;
        width:100%;
        height: 80px;
        position:relative;
        bottom: -500px; /* push to the bottom */
        padding-bottom: -500px; /* maintain equilibrium by giving footer its height!!*/
    }
```

**EDIT**

**to make footer stretch to height, if content exceeds**

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7pfMF/1/)

```
#footer {
        background: #365F91;
        color: #000000;
        width:100%;
        min-height: 80px; /*change height to min-height, this will always cover the content height*/
        position:relative;
        bottom: -500px;
        padding-bottom: -500px;

    }
```

**If you want a scrollable footer if content exceeds**

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7pfMF/2/)

```
#footer {
        background: #365F91;
        color: #000000;
        width:100%;
        height: 80px; /*keep height fixed*/
        overflow-y:scroll; /*scroll when content size increases */
        position:relative;
        bottom: -500px;
        padding-bottom: -500px;

    }
```

Comment: that works, but I want the footer staying at the bottom of the page.  if the content goes below the footer i would want the footer sticking to the bottom and scrollbar showing content.

Comment: you mean that you would want a scrollbar in the footer if content exceed the height??

Comment: @user3036496 : added 2 more variants...please check if the **EDIT** part helps!!

Comment: that didn't fix the problem, just doesnt show because there is no background image.  once background image shows the white space under the content is gone.  I want to have a div extend to the footer regardless of the content on it.  I only want the background image to show on the sides while the middle is white with content, without adding 2 additional divs on the side just to house the background

Comment: same as previous, the footer is staying in the same place but without the background image you cant see that the div does not extend down to footer

Comment: @user3036496 : ok..let me have a look again!!

Comment: you have `</li>` missing in your markup here => `<li><a href='C:\site final\quality.html#pressurepaper'><span>Documentation</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>`

Comment: @user3036496 : chat would have been helpful..but u don't have enough rep...ur css needs lot of work...its screwed up badly!!

Comment: @user3036496 : remove `position:relative;` from `#wrapper` and then go through this fiddle, this is what you have for solution finally => http://jsfiddle.net/F2SMX/7/

Comment: that still isnt what im looking for....i dont want gray between the content and the footer.  I want the content div (#page) to extend all the way to the footer regardless of the content, whether 1 line or 200 lines, and it isnt working

Comment: @user3036496 : give me live url.....fiddle and your question is more time taking than i thought!!

Comment: I dont have the files uploaded to the host yet, so ive pasted the html and css into pastebin so you can just copy it and save as html file.  Ive reworked the css as well to try to clean up unused portions.  the footer is working now, just cant extend the 'body' div down to the footer without adding content to it.(http://pastebin.com/FgYB3JLq) index html      (http://pastebin.com/j5NwN5wu) css file

Comment: @user3036496 : your HTML has no `body` tag...correct your markup first dude!! :)

Comment: @user3036496 : do u have a gmail-id so that we can chat there...its getting bulky in here!! :)

Comment: is there a way to message you directly so i dont have to put my info on here?

Answer (score 2):

Change `relative` to `absolute`, and remove `min-height` from `#page`.

```
#footer { position: absolute; }
```

You'll also need to make sure that you only have 1 `#page` per page.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2SMX/3/).

Comment: correct me if m wrong...but what i deduced from question is that footer should be scrollable...you have fixed it!!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something called sticky footer.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Or you can use my solution without using pseudo class `:after`

EDIT: sorry here you have my solution to problem with div instead of after http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LsFIn